# Inverse of matrix (Hermitian matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Inverse of matrix**

How to calculate  the inverse for this expression?
$$[(A+B)(A+B)^H]^{-1}$$

while

A and B are vectors contain complex values

$^H$ is hermitian

and 
$^{-1}$ is inverse

Thanks

Comment: $A,B$ are vectors!? Then your matrix is of the form $vv^H$? This matrix is not invertible. To see this take any vector $w$ orthogonal to $v$, i.e. such that $v^H w=0$. Then $(vv^H)w=0$ with $w\neq 0$.

Comment: Ditto. $vv^H$ is rank one.